# Error running npm command TypeError: mkdirp is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm

I already tried to uninstall the Nodejs and reinstall an other version but I keep on getting this error every time I run the command `npm install` or `npm`. when I try `npm -v` it returns the version.

My current installed nodejs versions is 10.16.0 and NPM is 6.12.0.

> TypeError: mkdirp is not a function
>       at Conf.setUser (C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\set-user.js:22:3)
>       at Conf.loadExtras (C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:225:8)
>       at Conf. (C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:166:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
>       at Conf.emit (events.js:198:13)
>       at ConfigChain._resolve (C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:281:34)
>       at ConfigChain.add (C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\config-chain\index.js:259:10)
>       at Conf.add (C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:338:27)
>       at Conf. (C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:314:25)
>       at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:90:16)
>   C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:59
>         throw new Error('npm.load() required')
>         ^

Error: npm.load() required
    at Object.get (C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:59:13)
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Users\mrosus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:32)
    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27)

Comment: Deleting manually the npm folder inside AppData\Roaming solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, what happened to me was that I changed the version of my node, using a node version manager, I use the "n" https://github.com/tj/n . It turns out that when changing the version I did not see that I had given several error messages "Permission denied", that is, I thought I had changed the version but there was not, that somehow bugged my node and when I tried to use any command with npm it gave mistake.

To solve it, I simply changed the version using sudo, in my case, as I use the "n" node version manager, I ran the "sudo n" command and chose the node version.

Comment: running sudo n still did not fix the issue for me.